# Operator overloading adding two objects error

Tags: c++, object, operator-overloading

I have no idea why this code should work, but tell me what to do if i want to add two objects
together. please. while you are trying to answer please be more noob specific

sorry for my bad english, I am an Indian, here is my code.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class time
{
private:
    int sec;
    int mint;
    int hours;
public:
    int Inputsec;
    int Inputmint;
    int Inputhours;
time(int Inputsec, int Inputmint, int Inputhours):sec(Inputsec), mint(Inputmint), hours(Inputhours){};
time operator+(time Inputobj)
{
    time blah (sec+Inputsec,mint+Inputmint,hours+Inputhours);
    return blah;
}

void DisplayCurrentTime()
{
    cout << "The Current Time Is"<<endl<< hours<<" hours"<<endl<<mint<<"minutes"<<endl<<sec<<"seconds"<<endl;
}
};

int main()
{
time now(11,13,3);
time after(13,31,11);
time then(now+after);
then.DisplayCurrentTime();
}
```

code is working fine but it is giving me horrible output.
Where is my mistake?

Comment: Being Indian is no excuse for an incomplete topic - copy/paste that 'horrible output' and we might actually understand some of it.

Comment: " horrible output"?  How about telling us the actual and expected output?

Comment: Also note: `time` already exists in `ctime` header.

Comment: 'I am an Indian',how does that relate to being bad in English?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your addition operator is using unitinitialized member `Inputsec`, `Inputmint` and `Inputhours` variables. It should look like this:

```
time operator+(time Inputobj)
{
    return time(sec+InputObj.sec, mint+InputObj.mint, hours+InputObj.hours);
}
```

or

```
time operator+(time Inputobj)
{
    InputObj.sec += sec;
    InputObj.mint += mint;
    InputObj.hours += hours;
    return InputObj;
}
```

Or, even better, implement `time& operator+=(const time& rhs);` and use it in a non-member addition operator:

```
time operator+(time lhs, const time& rhs)
{
  return lhs += rhs;
}
```

You have two sets of member variables representing the same thing. You do not need this duplication.

One final remark: there is something called `std::time` in header`<ctime>`. Having a class called `time`, and `using namespace std` is asking for trouble. You should avoid both if possible (avoiding the second is definitely possible).

Comment: Thank you juan, that expalins everything :)

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite your `operator+` **at least** as follows:

```
time operator+(time Inputobj)
{
    time blah time(sec+InputObj.sec, mint+InputObj.mint, hours+InputObj.hours);
    return blah;
}
```

also I think you should use the `%` operator for getting the correct time results:

```
time operator+(time Inputobj){
    int s = (sec+InputObj.sec) % 60;
    int m = (sec+InputObj.sec) / 60 + (mint+InputObj.mint) % 60;
    int h = (mint+InputObj.mint) / 60 + (hours+InputObj.hours) % 24;
    return time(s,m,h);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your operator overloading function is using uninitialized variables. Initialize variables `inputsec, inputmint, Inputhours` in your constructor.

Moreover, try this:

```
time operator+ (time Inputobj)
{
   time blah (sec+Inputobj.sec, mint+Inputobj.mint, hours+Inputobj.hours);
   return blah;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is your publics members with the same name as the parameter constructor, which are unitialized.
Try this :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class time
{
private:
    int sec;
    int mint;
    int hours;
public:
time(int Inputsec, int Inputmint, int Inputhours):sec(Inputsec), mint(Inputmint), hours(Inputhours)
{
};

time operator+(time Inputobj)
{
    time blah (sec+Inputobj.sec, mint+Inputobj.mint, hours+Inputobj.hours);
    return blah;
}

void DisplayCurrentTime()
{
    cout << "The Current Time Is"<<endl<< hours<<" hours"<<endl<<mint<<"minutes"<<endl<<sec<<"seconds"<<endl;
}
};

int main()
{
time now(11,13,3);
time after(13,31,11);
time then(now+after);
then.DisplayCurrentTime();
}
```

Comment: Setters/Getters should not be created just for the sake of it, especially for something like an overloaded + operator, as a class has access to private members of it's own type when they are used as input parameters, so you can directly call Inputobj.sec within the + operator function.